# Symfony doctrine - Parent Child not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table "nodes", with the columns id, parent_id and so on...

```
/**
 * Node
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="nodes", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="parent", columns={"parent_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="path", columns={"path"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Node
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parentId;

    ...
}
```

Now I want to build the parent-child relationsship (parent_id is a foreign key to the same table's id). Based on the symfony cookbook example for Relations (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) I tried to create it:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Node", mappedBy="parent")
 */
protected $children;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Node", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $parent;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

My first problem is, that the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

Didn't create the getters and setters for parent and child (no error message, just the normal "generating..." message)

So I created the getters and setters by myself:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getParent() {
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $parent
 */
public function setParent( $parent ) {
    $this->parent = $parent;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getChildren() {
    return $this->children;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $children
 */
public function setChildren( $children ) {
    $this->children = $children;
}
```

But this seems not to work. I can't fetch for example the parent of a node or the children with:

```
$node->getParent();
$node->getChildren();
```

Both commands retun null, but the data is correct. The code even didn't try to query for parent or children.

Comment: Have you already looked through logs and profiler output?

Comment: Yes. Thats the output of the command line output and log: http://pastebin.com/mJU3Fp7h

Comment: And the profiler just shows me 1 query (the query to fetch $node itself) and NO other query to fetch the $node->getParent() or $node->getChildren().

Comment: As for me, everything looks OK in your `Node` entity.

Comment: for me as well, but its not working ;). How should the getters and setters exactly look like?

Comment: Setters and Getters do not have any influence, as `Doctrine` does not use them — it uses `Reflection` to set the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out why I had this (stupid) problem. Since I had initially generated my entities with reverse engineering of the tables (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html), I had doctrine YML files in my config (the where autogenerated). It seems, that if you have such files, symfony/doctrine use them instead of the annotations. Thats it. I just had to delete them. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class is defined like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Node
{
  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children= new ArrayCollection();
    }

     /**
 * Set parent
 *
 * @param \Bundle\Entity\Node $parent
 * @return Message
 */
public function setParent(\Bundle\Entity\Node $parent = null)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get parent
 *
 * @return \Bundle\Entity\Node 
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * Add children
 *
 * @param \Bundle\Entity\Node $children
 * @return Message
 */
public function addReply(\Bundle\Entity\Node $children)
{
    $this->children[] = $children;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove children
 *
 * @param \Bundle\Entity\Node $children
 */
public function removeReply(\Bundle\Entity\Node $children)
{
    $this->children->removeElement($children);
}

/**
 * Get children
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->children;
}
}
```

Then try the entity generation command again. And don't forget to update schema.

Comment: I had this annotation already there (updated my question to show you more of the code). The entity itself is working. I can get other properties (for example getName()) without problems.

Comment: Would adding the constructor like in the edit solve your issue? Set children as an arraycollection. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Ehm. As you can see in my question, I have already done this before (as descriped in the cookbook).

Comment: Alright, one last idea otherwise, sorry: targetEntity="Node" try setting the full namespace to the Node class here in both fields, so: targetEntity="Bundle\Folder\Node" . I hope this would work.

Comment: That is how your getters and setters should look like. The paramaters need typecasting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94332/discussion-between-leftjustified-and-george-irimiciuc).

Comment: Thanks for getter and setter example, but as far as I know, php-docs doesn't change anything on the behaviour of doctrine. I tried your examples, but the do not solve my problem.

Comment: check : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing    it works

Comment: ehm. yes, I know the docs. and if you have a look at my question, you can see, that I have done it exactly as described. but its not working.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I have a similar example to yours on one of my projects but it worked without problems.